# Increasing precision of the HERE.com geocoder

Tags: here-api

I am a researcher and my lab is currently evaluating the possibility of using HERE.com's geocoder as an alternative to Google Maps. We are running into some major issues with precision in the geocoder, because the smallest distances that can be discriminated between with the default 5 decimal limit is larger than the distance between about 25% of the parcels we are geocoding. Is there a way to increase the precision of the geocoder? I wasn't able to find anything relevant in the documentation.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some of your sample calls?

Comment: Any examples?
I tried for example two house numbers of the same street next to each other  and the results are very precise:
1: https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.11.0&apikey=...&searchText=Eberswalder%20Str.%2034%2C%20Berlin
2: https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.11.0&apikey=...&searchText=Eberswalder%20Str.%2033%2C%20Berlin

Here are results on the map: https://prnt.sc/qrv5t1

Comment: @RaymondCamden I am using the batch geocoder, https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?apiKey=...&indelim=,&outdelim=,&action=run&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,navigationLatitude,navigationLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,city,postalCode,state&outputcombined=false&header=true

Comment: @Tomas one example would be 18 and 20 Nonantum Street in the Brighton neighbourhood of Boston, MA - these are separate properties in Boston's assessors map with coordinates of (-71.1683401599097 42.3496700672577) and (-71.1684857918368 42.3495650427435), respectively - in HERE data these both appear as (-71.16882, 42.34951). These geocode to separate locations using the Google geocoder.

Comment: Edgar, please see my answer below for this example. The precision should really be enough for package delivery (it's being used to deliver a huge amount of packages every day). However, if you have other examples, please let me know.

Comment: @leopectus thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that for some reason 20 Nonantum Street wasn't in our database. Curiously, this is the only house on the street that was missing.

Since the Geocoder couldn't find the address, is was then resolving to the next closest number, which is 18. This is why both addresses resolved to the same location. It resolved 18 Nonantum correctly and also used it as a fallback for 20 Nonantum.

I've submitted an edit to the database. Once this has been verified but our map content team, the address should start resolving correctly. Thank you for reporting this!

Comment: As an additional note, if you ever find an error or missing data in our map, you can submit your own changes using [MapCreator](https://mapcreator.here.com).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there any indication for if the geocoder resolved to the next closest number? It's very important that we not accidentally geocode to a nearby property because we sometimes work on the street level and this would skew results.

Comment: @Edgar, maybe it would be nice to update the question so everyone knows that it was one particular case and not the general problem of HERE geoocder?

Comment: The response from the Geocoder contains a MatchLevel and MatchQuality data, so you will know if a response is e.g., on a street level or a house number level.